# Rhythmbox plugin code for hot key not working - why?

Tags: python, programming, rhythmbox, plugins

```
def activate(self,shell):
  self.shell = shell
  self.copy_selected()
  self.action = gtk.Action ('foo','bar','baz',None)
  self.activate_id = self.action.connect ('activate', self.call_bk_fn,self.shell)
  self.action_group = gtk.ActionGroup ('hot_key_action_group')
  self.action_group.add_action_with_accel (self.action, "<control>E")

  uim = shell.get_ui_manager ()
  uim.insert_action_group (self.action_group, 0)
  uim.ensure_update ()
def call_bk_fn():
                print('hello world')
```

I am using the above code in a plugin for Rhythmbox and here I am trying to register the key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> so that the `call_bk_fn` gets called whenever the key combination is pressed but its not working.

Why is that so ?

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19711/how-can-i-listen-to-a-specific-signal-in-rhythmbox/19713#19713) basically applies here too. Also, you may have a better chance of a good answer on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Rhythmbox%20plugin%20code%20for%20hot%20key%20not%20working%20-%20why?&tags=rhythmbox%20python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no Knowledge about the plugin your using.

However Ubuntu has another solution for this:-)

Go to: System>Preferences>Keyboard Shortcuts

right at the top under "sound" you can set action keys including a next track, play, pause, volume down, etc.

Comment: i figured that out , made a plugin for it .. you can download it as well . who knows may be you might like it .